Cumulative sum product with previous values (Pyspark)
all good?
I need some help to do cumulative sum of a sumproduct, i have a db like that:
dfz = spark.createDataFrame( [
    (202401, 20240101, 20,     0, 0.1, 20.0),
    (202401, 20240102, 50,    20, 0.2, 50.0),
    (202401, 20240103, 20,    50, 0.2, 20.0),
    (202401, 20240104, None,  20, 0.2, None),
    (202401, 20240105, None,   0, 0.3, None),
    (202401, 20240106, None,   0, 0.1, None)], 
    ["year_month", "date", "amount", "amount_lag", "perc_prev", "amount_prev"] )

+----------+--------+------+----------+---------+-----------+
|year_month|    date|amount|amount_lag|perc_prev|amount_prev|
+----------+--------+------+----------+---------+-----------+
|    202401|20240101|    20|         0|      0.1|       20.0|
|    202401|20240102|    50|        20|      0.2|       50.0|
|    202401|20240103|    20|        50|      0.2|       20.0|
|    202401|20240104|  NULL|        20|      0.2|       NULL|
|    202401|20240105|  NULL|      NULL|      0.3|       NULL|
|    202401|20240106|  NULL|      NULL|      0.1|       NULL|
+----------+--------+------+----------+---------+-----------+

So, i need to calculate the amount_prev, which is ("amount_lag" * "perc_prev") + "amount lag", the problem is, the amount_prev only calculate when "amount" is equal zero and when "amount_lag" is null we use the lag of the "amount_prev", the final db will be like that:
dfz = spark.createDataFrame( [
    (202401, 20240101, 20,     0, 0.1, 20.0),
    (202401, 20240102, 50,    20, 0.2, 50.0),
    (202401, 20240103, 20,    50, 0.2, 20.0),
    (202401, 20240104, None,  20, 0.2, 24.0),
    (202401, 20240105, None,   0, 0.3, 31.2),
    (202401, 20240106, None,   0, 0.1, 34.32)], 
    ["year_month", "date", "amount", "amount_lag", "perc_prev", "amount_prev"] )

+----------+--------+------+----------+---------+-----------+
|year_month|    date|amount|amount_lag|perc_prev|amount_prev|
+----------+--------+------+----------+---------+-----------+
|    202401|20240101|    20|         0|      0.1|       20.0|
|    202401|20240102|    50|        20|      0.2|       50.0|
|    202401|20240103|    20|        50|      0.2|       20.0|
|    202401|20240104|  NULL|        20|      0.2|       24.0|
|    202401|20240105|  NULL|        24|      0.3|       31.2|
|    202401|20240106|  NULL|        31|      0.1|      34.32|
+----------+--------+------+----------+---------+-----------+

The step-by-step is:
|year_month|    date|amount|amount_lag|perc_prev|amount_prev|
|    202401|20240103|    20|        50|      0.2|       20.0|
|    202401|20240104|  NULL|        20|      0.2|       NULL|

Look, in 20240104 i don't have the amount value, but have amount_lag, so i calculated the amount_prev by ("amount_lag" * "amount_prev") + "amount_lag"), ((20 * 0,2)+20) and i get the value 24
|year_month|    date|amount|amount_lag|perc_prev|amount_prev|
|    202401|20240103|    20|        50|      0.2|       20.0|
|    202401|20240104|  NULL|        20|      0.2|       24.0|
|    202401|20240105|  NULL|      NULL|      0.3|       NULL|

Now, we need to calculated the "amount_prev" of 20240105, and i don't have neither amount_lag or amount, just the amount_prev, what i calculated in the line before, so i calculated (("amount_prev" * "perc_prev") + "amount_prev") ((24*0,3)+24) and get 31,2
|year_month|    date|amount|amount_lag|perc_prev|amount_prev|
|    202401|20240103|    20|        50|      0.2|       20.0|
|    202401|20240104|  NULL|        20|      0.2|       24.0|
|    202401|20240105|  NULL|      NULL|      0.3|       31.2|

I tried this:
w1 = (
      Window.partitionBy("year_month", "date")
      .orderBy('date').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

test = (
    dbz
    .withColumn('amount_prev', 
                when((~col('amount').isNull()), col('amount'))
                .otherwise((col('amount_lag')*col('perc_prev'))+col('amount_lag'))
               )
)

But didn't worked, anyone can help me?
I tried sum by a window, but it didnt cumulative sum by the year_month, i expect a function to calculate a database like the second example

"calculate the amount_prev, which is ("amount_lag" * "perc_prev") + "amount lag", the problem is, the amount_prev only calculate when "amount" is equal zero and when "amount_lag" is null we use the lag of the "amount_prev" <-- This whole thing is very unclear. Can you break it down in bullet points and add examples?

for sure, i breaked in bullets and edited, can you look again?

still something is wrong. ("amount_lag" * "amount_prev") + "amount_lag"), ((20 * 0,2)+20) is not correct. amount_prev is NULL for that row. Did you mean perc_prev instead of amount_prev?
